# get the distinct values for a column in four tables by SQL server 2008, but it very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get the distinct values for a column  in four tables by SQL server 2008.
All tables have about 8 columns and 80,000 rows. All column values are int, varchar, or double.

The query column is int.

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct a.id) as a_num_distinc_id, 
     COUNT(distinct b.id) as b_num_distinc_id, 
     COUNT(distinct c.id) as c_num_distinc_id, 
     COUNT(distinct d.id) as d_num_distinc_id
FROM table1 as a, table2 as b
     table3 as c, table4 as d
```

If I get the distinct values for the column  for each table one by one, it run fast. But, if I run them together. It run very very slow, even more than 20 minutes.

Why ? thanks !

**UPDATE -------------------------------------------------**

I have solve the above problem from your answers. 
Now, I have a new one, which is related to OP but different.
I have a very large table 1 billion rows and 12 columns, which are int, double, varchar.
I need to know the distinct values for each volumn. 
Althought I use

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct a.id) as num_dist_id
 FROM my_large_table as a
```

It is very slow.

Are there better ways to do that  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing a humongous cross join on all the tables.  Simple rule:  Never use a comma in the `from` clause.

You can get what you want with nested subqueries in the `select` clause:

```
  SELECT (select COUNT(distinct a.id) from table1 a) as a_num_distinc_id, 
         (select COUNT(distinct b.id) from table2 b) as b_num_distinc_id, 
         (select COUNT(distinct c.id) from table3 c) as c_num_distinc_id, 
         (select COUNT(distinct d.id) from table4 d) as d_num_distinc_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because when you run them together, you're creating a Cartesian product of all the values in all the tables.

Try

```
 select
      (select COUNT(distinct a.id) From table1) as a_num_distinc_id,
      (select COUNT(distinct b.id) From table2) as b_num_distinc_id,
      (select COUNT(distinct c.id) From table3) as c_num_distinc_id,
      (select COUNT(distinct d.id) From table4) as d_num_distinc_id
```

Comment: @user3448011 You should post it as a new question